# Close webview after they have successfully logged in?

Tags: android, android-webview

So i am trying to make an app where when they open the app they are asked to log in. once they log in though i want to be able to close the webview automatically and "scrape" their account information off and be able to input it into my code. how would i do this?

Comment: did you tried something by yourself? show your efforts first

Answer (score 0):

In Android WebView you can:

- call java methods from webview javascript page (you can find many
  examples in this site)
- call javascript methods from java
- you can handle webview redirects to a certain page (just override method shouldOverrideUrlLoading).